# How to left join a Cartesian product on another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using Access 2010.  Suppose I have three tables: `dogs`, `cats`, and `catChases`.  My goal is to create a query that will tell me, for each dog and each cat, whether or not that dog has chased that cat.

I thought I'd have to use a Cartesian product of `dogs` and `cats`, because I want the status for all possible combinations, and then left join `catChases`, as follows:

```
select
dog,cat,chase
from
dogs,cats
left join
catChases
on
dogs.dog=catChases.dog
```

but that just gives me an error message:
`Syntax error in JOIN operation.`

So how do I left join another table to a Cartesian product?

Comment: Do u want to know which all dogs chased the cats or which all cats were chased by the dogs.Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select x.dog, x.cat,cs.chase 
from 
     (select dog
            ,cat  
     from dogs, cats) x
left join catChases cs on cs.dog=x.dog and x.cat=cs.cat
```

Comment: `AND cs.cat = x.cat`, presumably, or you'll join each combination of a given dog and cat with *all* the dog's chases...